# User Management with Admin Dashboard system in Next.js and Typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-fullstack

How can I build a web project in which I have to design a system in which multiple users are there and 1 admin is present. Users can make transactions to admin's account. Admin can see a dashboard of users and related payments. Users can also see their past transactions. What database I should use for this, I have started this  by using nextjs, typescript, mongodb. It will be a real time project and will deploy it. I didn't make a system like this previously. How can I proceed further ?